# What do theologians study about?

Tags: metaphysics, theology

I have never seen a word which is as ill defined as the word "God". Consider a group of 10 people, if we ask them what do they mean by God.I am certain all of them will have different definitions. Yet , everybody seems pretty convinced in the existence of this particular "word" .To some people it is some higher "power". Well, what do they mean by this higher "power". Some people say its love.They have to define it clearly. Some people take literal definitions given in religious texts, like the God who sits in the sky.

Well theologians, what do you really study about ? I am not criticizing something or someone, but I cannot understand.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about philosophy per se. Can you connect the dots a little better? (this is an SE about philosophy).

Comment: Well, most people find solace in their existential crisis, by believing in this word "god". But, everybody has different definitions. I am wondering, what form of existence, a theologians mean when they say "God exists" . Isn't it related to philosophy ?

Comment: Even with your comment, the question is still too broad. There are many philosophies and thousands of 'churches', all with different definitions... A short and clear answer cannot be given as it stands. Please edit your question to limit the scope to a particular philosopher or religious philosophy. - As an aside I can tell you the answer, I think, you are looking for is not really philosophical, since 'God' is _a matter of faith_ not logic or reason.

Comment: @MathewsGeorge *everything* is related to philosophy if you try hard enough, but that doesn't mean everything is a good fit for asking a question on an SE about philosophy.

Comment: At least for Christian religion, see [Theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theology#Definition) : "Augustine of Hippo defined the Latin equivalent, *theologia*, as "reasoning or discussion concerning the Deity"; Richard Hooker defined "theology" in English as "the science of things divine"."

Comment: It's largely a branch of philosophy dealing with religious problems. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy for example

Comment: More that of study of religion, I guess.

Comment: Anyway, this post seems more that of a critique and not actually of a question. You already know they study many different things, each of his own, and that there is no universal definition. What is the question beyond that? Studying religion makes sense. But religion is defined by community, not an individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What do theologians study about?*

The theologist [Thomas Altizer](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/02/obituaries/thomas-altizer-dies-at-91.html) studied a lot about Nothing in this book:-

[Godhead and the Nothing](https://vdocuments.us/altizer-godhead-and-the-nothing.html)

> (page 1)
>
> While there are innumerable names of God in our languages,
>   mythologies, and traditions, we now know that there is no possibility
>   whatsoever of reconciling these into a common name of God, or a
>   universal image of God, or a universal concept of God. ...
>
> To actually or fully to speak of God in our world is to evoke a wholly
>   mysterious, or vacuous, or annihilating presence. And what is most
>   manifestly missing in our world is an actual pronunciation of the name
>   of God in a genuine moment of affirmation, or in a full moment of life
>   and energy and body, or in a moment when we are truly awake.
>
> Now it is true that a genuinely mystical naming of God has inevitably
>   been a naming of mystery, and the deeper the mystical naming the
>   deeper the evocation of nothingness, dark night, and abyss, so that a
>   mystical naming of God is finally a calling forth of unknowing, and
>   the deepest possible unknowing, or the deepest possible silence. ...
>
> (page 13)
>
> All too significantly no such nothingness is actually known in any
>   Western theological tradition, and while it has at least indirectly
>   entered a uniquely modern Christian theology, it has never done so
>   fully or decisively, and this despite its deep impact upon both
>   Kierkegaard and Heidegger, to say nothing of Hegel, Schelling, and
>   Nietzsche. So, too, an absolute nothingness has been deeply and
>   comprehensively envisioned by Blake, Goethe, Dostoyevsky, and
>   Mallarmé, just as it has purely and even totally been called forth by
>   Joyce, Kafka, Stevens, and Beckett. Yet it has not yet been
>   theologically understood, and not yet fully confronted theologically,
>   and this despite the fact that those thinkers and visionaries who most
>   fully engaged an absolute nothingness thereby clearly established
>   truly new theological horizons.